# You have already activated spring 1.3.6, but your Gemfile requires spring 1.3.3. (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I encountered the same issue today with a suggestion:
Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

Prepending **bundle exec** didn't help (I was doing that already).

**spring stop** & **spring restart** did not help.

I need to do : **bundle update spring**
that works for me.

is there any better solution to fix using the spring version in previous gemlock file?

Answer (score 9):

I delete `gemfile.lock` and run `bundle` that usually clears things up.

Otherwise just remove `gem "spring"` from `Gemfile` and run `bundle`

Comment: thanks for your comment ,but most updated gems may have spring dependencies

Answer (score 3):

In my case I fixed this issue by running this command

```
bundle update spring
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not using the newer `spring` version anywhere, so running `gem uninstall spring` and selecting the option to delete the `1.3.6` version solved my problem. This way I did not have to change the `Gemfile.lock` file.

Answer (score -1):

run

```
gem update spring
```

your gemfile locked a new version of spring
but your production doesn't have it
run that command to update the gem in production
or require the version you already have in production in your gemfile